# Xcode stopped showing predictions

Tags: iphone, xcode

I use Xcode 4.0.1..Suddenly I noticed that my xcode stopped showing predictions...(for example if I use the name of the button and after that it use to show all the property of the button such as enabled,hidden etc)...My Xcode isn't showing any predictions now, it leads to some errors and consuming long time with out these predictions..Where I want to change this settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes exiting XCode and restarting clears up strange behavior like this.   Also, Mac OS X needs a reboot from time to time.  Unfortunate, but true.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you haven't imported the correct class(es)?

Comment: Good point - that is also where I have had the failure.  Especially if you forward reference a class and have not declared the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem when I get the compiler confused -- like during a refactoring and a large block of code, protocol names, interface properties, etc. are being changed.  I will clean and compile -- allow the errors, then it starts to work again.

Also, if I have unbalanced braces, brackets, parenthesis, etc.  that precedes the code I am working on, then it will stop autocompletion.  As soon as I balance the statement(s), it works again.  Sometimes, I have to clean and recompile.